# Getting NotImplementedError while training ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to use the ARIMA algorithm on a time series dataset. Everything is fine until I initialize the model.

Once I initialized the ARIMA model, I am getting the error:

```
    28 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ---> 29     raise NotImplementedError(ARIMA_DEPRECATION_ERROR)

    NotImplementedError: 
    statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have
    been removed in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the .
    between arima and model) and statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX.

    statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA makes use of the statespace framework and
    is both well tested and maintained. It also offers alternative specialized
    parameter estimators.
```

Please help me to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing a deprecated ARIMA model. The class `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA` is no longer available in newer versions of statsmodels. Somewhere in your code you import the model with something like this:

`from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA`

Just replace it with the newer model:

`from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA`

Then it should work again. Perhaps you have to change some parameters though, check the documentation for that:
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy, then paste this code to the Anaconda Environment, it will replace the "Multiple Error":

`conda install -c conda-forge pmdarima`

Link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pmdarima